# Delete all files older than a specific file name?

Tags: linux, backup, script

I want to be able to look for the most recent file ending in .backup, and delete ALL files that are older than that file (but of course keep newer files).

Here is an example of a directory listing where you can see multiple backups done.  I would desire to keep the files 000000020000000000000083.00000020.backup and 000000010000000000000082 but somehow delete everything older.

I can think of many hack ways to accomplish this, like doing a find with -mtime and deleting older than a day, which may work for me but isnt *correct*.  I could also do a listing of the directory BEFORE I do my backup, then compare it to afterwards and delete all files that were prior.  That still isn't correct.

Any ideas?

```
$ ls -ltr
total 131084
-rw-r-----. 1 cm800 cm800        0 May  6 13:58 archive_06_05_14___13_58_05
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 13:58 00000001000000000000007F
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 13:58 000000020000000000000080
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 13:58 000000020000000000000081
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800      242 May  6 13:58 00000001000000000000007F.00000020.backup
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800      242 May  6 13:58 000000020000000000000081.00000020.backup
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 14:03 000000010000000000000080
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 14:06 000000020000000000000082
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 14:06 000000010000000000000081
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 14:07 000000020000000000000083
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800      242 May  6 14:07 000000020000000000000083.00000020.backup
-rw-------. 1 cm800 cm800 16777216 May  6 14:11 000000010000000000000082
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-nt`, `-ot` operators to test whether a file is newer/older than another one:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

# Find the newest backup file:
unset newest
for f in *.backup ; do
    [[ $newest ]] || newest=$f           # Initialize.
    [[ $f -nt $newest ]] && newest=$f    # Keep the newest so far.
done

# Delete all the older files:
for f in * ; do
    [[ $f -ot $newest ]] && rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: You may also want to consider more efficent sorting algorithms... http://www.bashguru.com/2011/01/quicksort-shell-script.html

Comment: @EricG: I'm not sorting. I'm searching for the minimum. The whole thing is O(n).

Comment: This works well, unless you, for some reason, modified one of your wal archives (mv/cp/touch whatever...) and the modify time is changed. You can rely on the name of the file to search/delete - `[[ "$f" < "$newest" ]]`